# What is the difference between IE11 compatibility mode and IE10 compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode

Does both  IE11 compatibility mode and IE10 compatibility mode render in IE7 mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't just one "compatibility mode", but several.

All IE versions between v8 and v11 offer compatibility modes. There is a compatibility mode available for each previous version of IE as far back as IE7.

Therefore IE8 offers IE7-compatibility mode, IE9 offers modes for IE8 and IE7 compatibility, IE10 has modes for IE7, IE8 and IE9 compatibility, and IE11 offers modes for IE7, IE8, IE9 and IE10.

Between all the browser versions, the compatibility modes are reasonably consistent. Thus IE7 mode works much the same in IE8 as it does in IE11.

There is also a thing called Quirks Mode, which is a compatibility mode for IE5.5. Note that in IE11, there are two different Quirks Modes. The original quirks mode continues to work exactly as it always did in IE10 and earlier. This means that in addition to changing the rendering layout, it also switches off all the new browser features so that it works as close to IE5.5 as possible. However the newer quirks mode in IE11 doesn't do this; it just changes the rendering mode. This makes it work more like quirks mode in other browsers. IE11 has both of these modes, but IE10 only has the original one. Depending on how you trigger quirks mode, therefore, you may find it working differently. If you want it working the same between both IE10 and IE11, you need to make sure you use the original quirks mode.

Note that Microsoft's new browser Edge, which replaces IE, does not support any of these compatibility modes or quirks modes. You should therefore avoid relying on them, because IE will eventually disappear in favour of Edge.